# How to modify the default Wordpress 'Pages' widget to have titles on the anchor tags?

Tags: pages, widgets

So basically, the 'Pages' widget just prints out a list of all pages names as links (as you all probably know).

Although, these anchor tags do not have any titles, and that is frowned upon in the SEO world.

I would like to modify this to have the titles simply as the name of the page.

For example, I would like to turn this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="page_item page-item-3307"><a href="http://www.domain.com/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-3315"><a href="http://www.domain.com/blog/">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-100"><a href="http://www.domain.com/contact/">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Into this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="page_item page-item-3307"><a href="http://www.domain.com/about-us/" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-3315"><a href="http://www.domain.com/blog/" title="Blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-100"><a href="http://www.domain.com/contact/" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have had a look around within the `wp-includes/default-widgets.php` file, although it is all pushed through a function called `wp_list_pages`.

What must I do to achieve this?

PS. Using Wordpress 3.8.1

Answer (score 2):

A fast and short solution would be -

```
function wpse_list_pages( $output ){
    $output = preg_replace( '/<a(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/', '<a$1 title="$2">$2</a>', $output);
    return $output;
}
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'wpse_list_pages');
```

And if you want a proper way, you could extend `Walker_Page` (ref: post-template.php) class and set the Pages Widget walker to class with `widget_pages_args` hook